# using dllhost directly to host COM objects

Tags: c++, com, 32bit-64bit, atl, com+

I use IFilter (as a client) to search for text in files. Some document types like DOC have registered filter handlers for both 32 and 64 bit, but others like DOCX only register for one kind. If my program happens not to match the "bitness" of the IFilter component, it cannot use the IFilter object.

I have read of some registry tricks that can be used using [DllSurrogate](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/), however I don't want to interfere with my users' registry. I can write my own surrogate, but I am wondering whether I can take advantage of the default system surrogate DLLHOST, calling it directly to instantiate some COM class.

Has anybody tried it? Once I start DLLHOST with a particular /Processid:{clsid} how do I communicate with it from a separate process?

Comment: Well, I guess DllHost would do a `CoRegisterClassObject`, so `CoCreateInstance(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)` should find it... Unless it checks the registry first. Worth a try, I guess.

Comment: this is a reasonable suggestion but a few simple checks indicate that starting dllhost with the clsid of the required COM object as command line argument just exits immediately

Comment: the only way I had success invoking it directly is when all the required registry tweaks (a fake appid with empty dllsurrogate value) are in place. But that's not of much use because if the registry is modified you don't need to call dllhost directly. Windows explorer supposedly does that on the fly somehow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090212-00/?p=19173/

Comment: I don't think this goes anywhere. I compared dllhost actions with procmon and the first thing it tries to do is open HKCR\AppID\{clsid}, which doesn't exist in the general case. If it isn't there it quits immediately. So it is a deadend :(